# how to debug pure native code on android?

Tags: android, debugging, native-code

I have built a binary excutable from pure C++ code and it prompts time error when running on android device.

How can I debug the pure native code for android? It seems that the existing methods are not for pure native code.

Comment: I'd recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and try asking again to improve our ability to help you get an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have found the solution. Post here and hope it can help others bothered by this problem.

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1:** Put the *gdbserver*  and your ***unstripped*** *native binary executable* (suppose it is named testexec) on the android emulator. E.g. you can put it under folder /data/data/test. And use **chmod** command to add permissions to them.

**Step2:**  Start gdb debugger. And this step consists of following sub-steps:

**Step 2.1:** Start gdb debugger of the emulator by typing command on your host machine terminal:

```
 adb shell /data/data/test/gdbserver 10.0.2.2:1234 /data/data/test/testexec
```

The emulator will then listen on port 1234.

**Step 2.2**: Connect the gdb debugger of the local machine with the gdbserver of the emulator:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

It will prompt:

**Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands**

**OK**

Then input:

```
redir add tcp:1234:1234
```

to enable data redirection and then type

```
exit
```

**Step2.3**:  Start the gdb debugger of the local machine. Input:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe YOUR_ EXECUTABLE_PATH_ON_LOCAL_MACHINE\testexec
```

After that, input

```
target remote localhost:1234
```

to connect to the gdbserver.

Finally, enjoy your debugging!

Comment: would you know how to connect with telnet to real device  - not an emulator? i was trying to query for the ip with `adb shell ip -f inet addr show` but cannot connect

Answer (score -1):

Android supports the use of [GDB](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/how-cc-debugging-works-on-android/).  However, I should note that if by "pure C++" you mean that there is no Java at all in the application, this is technically not allowed (although you can definitely do it). See [the NDK page.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)